# How do i fix lack of the class in SimpleQR

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, qr-code

trying to generate qr code on my website on laravel 10 using SimpleQR, BaconQR. But getting this error all the time *Class "SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\QrCodeServiceProvider" not found*.

i checked multiple times that simpleqr was installed, added provider and alias to config/app.php,
tried reinstalling

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>QR Code Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>QR Code Generator</h1>
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {{ $qrCode }}">
</body>
</html>
```

```
Route::get('/qr-code', function () {
    $qrCode = QrCode::size(500)->generate('Hello, World!');
    return view('qrcode', compact('qrCode'));
});
```

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs> php composer.phar show -i             
bacon/bacon-qr-code            2.0.8 BaconQrCode is a QR code generator for PHP.
dasprid/enum                   1.0.4 PHP 7.1 enum implementation
simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode 4.2.0 Simple QrCode is a QR code generator made for Laravel.
```

still not getting what the problem is

Comment: Have you checked imagick extension is enabled or not?

Comment: The error is saying that the ServiceProvider cannot be found. I assume you already checked the class is in the correct folder under the vendor directory so, maybe running the command `composer dumpautoload` can help

Comment: @KamranAllana i am trying to enable it changing php.ini but i was getting and error, then i downloaded the imagick ant stil had same error
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_imagick.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll (╨Э╨╡ ╨╜╨░╨╣╨┤╨╡╨╜ ╤Г╨║╨░╨╖╨░╨╜╨╜╤Л╨╣ ╨╝╨╛╨┤╤Г╨╗╤М), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_imagick.dll.dll (╨Э╨╡ ╨╜╨░╨╣╨┤╨╡╨╜ ╤Г╨║╨░╨╖╨░╨╜╨╜╤Л╨╣ ╨╝╨╛╨┤╤Г╨╗╤М)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: @Lerzenit yeah i was trying that, i was also trying do composer update and etc